# How to implement Jquery on Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm

I getting an error on the following line

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I think this is because if have not install jquery in my laravel project.
For other packages I use npm. How can I install jQuery in laravel and how to set up the script type link correctly to my index page?

Comment: [download the script file](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js) and put it in your `public/js/` folder

Comment: You can use npm with laravel as well. Which laravel version did you use?

Comment: From what I understand, Laravel comes preset with jquery already.

Comment: When laravel comes with jquery already what i excatly i have to enter in my Index PHp to use it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 5.4, you can just run [`npm run dev`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix) and you'll get jQuery in your app.

Another simple way to add jQuery to your app is too use [CDN link](http://code.jquery.com/):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or download jQuery minified script to the `public/js` directory and do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my detailed answer at [How to use jquery-easing in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342580/how-to-use-jquery-easing-in-laravel/50343506#50343506). I have explained how to compile down all your dependencies including `jquery` easily into one file `public/js/app.js` using laravel-mix