# How to use/integrate jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Any idea how to deal with that? I mean do I need to install or manage some files in my project? I don't know how to manage that? Sorry I am just new in laravel

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? it will be in ````composer.json```` file

Comment: laravel 5.6 sir

Comment: there are several ways. would you like to know the advanced one?

Comment: its okay sir . I would like to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will share two ways

a) In your view add this line in html `head`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and start writing your jquery code in `script` tag

b) The other way which i generally prefer is :

In Laravel 5.6 if u look at your `package.json` file `jquery`is already present as npm dependency so

1. create new laravel project `laravel new my-project`
2. cd to `my-project` and run command `npm install`. This will install all dependencies included in `package.json` including `jquery`.
3. now to compile down all these dependencies to one file in `public/js/app.js` add the line `window.Jquery = require('jquery');`to your `resources/assets/js/app.js`
4. run command `npm run dev`
5. add line `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` to your `welcome.blade.php`
6. Run the server and see the output you will be seeing the default laravel page with some links below Laravel heading
7. add this code to your view now.

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".links").hide();
   });
   ```

refresh page. you will not see the links below laravel now. which means jquery is up and working

Comment: @rookie if your are new use the first solution. it is easy

Comment: No problem. Let me edit your question. So that other people can easily find the question and its Solution